# Using input text and Javascript for calculation

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have tried multiple ways to get result but i am unable to do so .. I am quite new in Javascript ..

For an example:

User input value "5" in "results2". Upon clicking the SGD button, I want the value in input to be change to the new value which will be UserInput * SGDRate .

This is my HTML code

```
<p class="heading">
This is a currencry converter for Singapore To Malaysia Currency </P>

<form name="currency">
<input type="text" name="results2">
<input type="button" value=SGD name="SGD" onclick="displayConversion(SGD.value)">
<input type="button" value="Please Click to find what is the latest Rate" name="help" onclick = "rates()">
</form>
```

As for my Javascript file

I know that I need to create another function but I am unsure where do I start.

```
var SGDrate = 2.92;
var convertrate = inputUser * SGDrate;

function displayConversion(n1)
{
currency.results2.value=n1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `value` of `input.result2` when using `onclick` event like this :

```
<input type="button" value=SGD name="SGD" onclick="displayConversion(document.getElementsByName('results2')[0].value)">
```

Then in your script you should calculate your equation into the function :

```
var SGDrate = 2.92;

function displayConversion(n1)
{
  var convertrate =n1 * SGDrate;
  currency.results2.value=convertrate;
}
```

See your example after those edits:

```js
var SGDrate = 2.92;

function displayConversion(n1)
{
  var convertrate =n1 * SGDrate;
  currency.results2.value=convertrate;
}
```

```html
<p class="heading">
  This is a currencry converter for Singapore To Malaysia Currency </p>

<form name="currency">
  <input type="text" name="results2">
  <input type="button" value=SGD name="SGD" onclick="displayConversion(document.getElementsByName('results2')[0].value)">
  <input type="button" value="Please Click to find what is the latest Rate" name="help" onclick = "rates()">
</form>
```

You also should check the input value by the user if it is `float` or not, in the following snippet I checked the value entered by the user and alert message if it is not `float`

```js
var SGDrate = 2.92;

function displayConversion(n1)
{
  if( !isNaN(parseFloat(n1)) ){
    var convertrate = parseFloat(n1) * SGDrate;
    currency.results2.value=convertrate;
  }
  else{
    alert("you must enter a number")
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="heading">
  This is a currencry converter for Singapore To Malaysia Currency </p>

<form name="currency">
  <input type="text" name="results2">
  <input type="button" value=SGD name="SGD" onclick="displayConversion(document.getElementsByName('results2')[0].value)">
  <input type="button" value="Please Click to find what is the latest Rate" name="help" onclick = "rates()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a few mistakes in your code:

1. You forgot to indent the code.
2. You closed the paragraph with `</P>` instead of `</p>`.
3. You need to pass `results2.value` to `displayConversion`, not `SGD.value`.
4. `convertrate` needs to be a function in order to be evaluated more than once.

Also you could have added an `id` attribute to `results2` to make it easier to change its value.

Here is the code with those problems fixed.

```js
function convertrate(rate) {
  var SGDrate = 2.92;
  return rate * SGDrate;
}

function displayConversion(rate) {
  var results2 = document.querySelector('#results2');
  results2.value = convertrate(rate);
}
```

```html
<p class="heading">
  This is a currencry converter for Singapore To Malaysia Currency
</p>

<form name="currency">
  <input type="text" id="results2" name="results2">
  <input type="button" value=SGD name="SGD" onclick="displayConversion(results2.value)">
  <input type="button" value="Please Click to find what is the latest Rate" name="help" onclick = "rates()">
</form>
```